# No se puede llamar a Invoke o a BeginInvoke en un control hasta que se haya creado el identificador de ventana

Tags: c#, windows-forms, hilos

En este caso cuando mi sistema llega a una parte donde descarga información de un servidor y pues eso lleva cierto tiempo, lo que quiero hacer es que se abra una ventana de loading que me diga que se sta descargando cosas, pero que esa nueva ventana o forms se inicie en otro hilo de ejecución para que la descargas que se hacen no la afecten y pueda mostrar información de forma rápida y sin tardar.

Código:

```
            LoadForm load = new LoadForm();

            if (!IsHandleCreated)
            {
                this.CreateControl();
            }



            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate () {
                load.ShowDialog();
            });
```

Error:

> No se puede llamar a Invoke o a BeginInvoke en un control hasta que se
>   haya creado el identificador de ventana.

Comment: Debes hacerlo al reves. La ventana debe ir en el hilo principal, y es la descarga de información que lleva tiempo la que debe ir en un hilo secundario.

Answer (score 1):

Las ventanas no se puden abrir en un thread diferente al de la aplicaicon principal, lo que si puedes lanzar es un thread para que la operacion de descarga no congele la UI y por consiguiente esta ventana de progreso

Para mostrar la ventana de "loading.." podrias simplemente lanzar un form con un `progress bar` en el cual definas el style como marquee

```
ProgressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 30
ProgressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee
```

Esto hara que se mueva indicando que estas trabajando, pero no tendras un avance de la tarea porque no conoces cuanto tardara.

Antes de mostrar el form puedes lanzar un thread, con al ayuda del `BackGroundWorker`

[Usando el ProgressBar con un BackGroundWorker](https://geeks.ms/eecsaky/2006/09/10/usando-el-progressbar-con-un-backgroundworker/)

podria ser algo como esto

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundActualizar.RunWorkerAsync();

    frmProgress frm = new frmProgress();
    frm.ShowDialog();
}

private void backgroundActualizar_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //aqui el codigo 
}
```